# Automate Account Teams based on lookup field

Tags: trigger, account, automation, account-teams

I have custom lookup fields to the user object for various members of our overlay teams, ex. sales engineer.

Can someone help with a trigger to add this user to the account team when the field is filled in at the account level?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE Stephanie! As it is, this question is a bit too broad hence the 'close question' votes from the community.  SFSE questions should typically include a code sample, showing what you've tried and exactly where you've gotten stuck. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example for update which you can modify for insert and update both.

```
trigger AccTrig on Account (after update) 
{
  Map<Id,Id> accShareId = new Map<Id,Id>();
  for(Integer i= 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++)
  {
    accShareId.put(Trigger.new[i].Id, Trigger.new[i].yourLookUpFieldName);
  }
    list<AccountTeamMember> lstToInsrt = new list<AccountTeamMember>();
    for(ID i: accShareId.keySet())
    {
     AccountTeamMember  atm = new AccountTeamMember( AccountId = i, UserId = accShareId.get(i));
     lstToInsrt.add(atm);
    }
    if(lstToInsrt.size() > 0)
        insert lstToInsrt;
}
```

Comment: Shailesh -- 1) trigger only handles update on Account event, not insert which is clearly possible given OP; 2) use of `i` to mean integer index and id value in same code object is not best practice; 3) how does this avoid adding the same ATM on the second update to the same Account (for some unrelated field); 4) How does it remove existing ATM if user changes lookup relationship?

Comment: @crop1645 : I know the code is not written per best practices. I just gave the basic idea to the user about adding the user to the account team. I'll try to edit my answer though. Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: @shailesh In re: best practices, see also: error handling, handler pattern (only flow control in trigger body)